# Create a xml file in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

My xml file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>items</key>
      <array>
          <dict>
              <key>assets</key>
              <array>
                  <dict>
                      <key>kind</key>
                      <string>software-package</string>
                      <key>url</key>
                      <string>http://172.16.147.75:3000/testfile/TestInstall.ipa</string>
                  </dict>
              </array>
              <key>metadata</key>
              <dict>
                  <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                  <string>MainStoryboard_iPad</string>
                  <key>bundle-version</key>
                  <string>1.0</string>
                  <key>kind</key>
                  <string>software</string>
                  <key>title</key>
                  <string>TestInstall</string>
              </dict>
          </dict>
      </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

and i want to generate this file using nokogiri or any other method or gem  please someone help me.

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse you can use the [nokogiri builder](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) as recommended byBaldrick

and to generate xml output to the file 
you can do:

```
xml_file = open(filename, 'w')
xml_file.write xml_string
xml_file.close
```

Or using the block syntax to achieve this in one line:

```
File.open(local_filename, 'w') { |f| f.write(xml_string) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

Below link provide you how to generate xml using nokogiri.

http://runnable.com/UjY9hE5ZnwIjAAED/how-to-create-xml-with-nokogiri-for-ruby-on-rails-and-csv